# Problems with volume on 5.1 videos

Tags: vlc-media-player, video-playback

As many video files are 5.1 now, and I only have a 2ch speaker setup, I hit this issue more and more.

The audio is horrendously unbalanced. Loud scenes such as gunfire, car chases, etc are unbearably loud. Turn it down though and then scenes with speech are way too quiet to hear.

Any solutions? I generally use VLC, on Windows 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use loudness equalization feature from Enhancements in Speaker properties accessed from control panel.

Control Panel→Hardware and Sound→Sound→Your default device→Properties→Enhancements tab→check the Loudness equalization option

Comment: This is driver-dependent and may not be available on all audio devices.

Comment: it is generally availabe in builtin soundcards in all motherboards. U could try that option and say.

Answer (score -1):

To choose stereo, go to Audio → Audio Device → Stereo.

Comment: I've done that, but it doesn't seem to normalise the audio correctly, as explained above. I guess that because speech is in just one of the channels (center) and the explosions are on many channels, that's why it sounds louder?

Comment: @MartinAlderson Not exactly, But you can change the equalizer in Tools→ Effects and Filters→Audio Effects choose headphones. It's supposed to be the best match for 2CH speakers.